# Deploying WAR in Tomcat by setting context docBase to HTTP url

Tags: maven, deployment, tomcat7, war, java-7

My environment for the issues is tomcat 7.0.67 and java 7.

I will like to use WAR file generated at internal maven repository
  for setting up context doc base in tomcat.

I created MyApp.xml under catalina_home/conf/Catalina/localhost as below

‹Context docBase="http://internalmvnrepository/repository/CURRENT/wars/MyApp-CURRENT.war" ›
‹/Context›

The different thing here is i will like to use  http url while setting up a docBase and not local/relative file path.

This didn't worked, tomcat couldn't load the context because tomcat documentation clearly says **docBase** should be  absolute pathname for the directory or WAR file.

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html

Any ideas on how to get this working or has got working in a  similar setup where organizations having their internal maven repo wants to deploy web application from a http URL and not relative path.